# Android height wrap_content with fix ratio

Tags: android, listview, height, android-linearlayout, android-wrap-content

My `XML` file has a `LinearLayout` containing two `ListView` with `android:height="wrap_content"`. However, when one of the `ListView` has too much contents, it pushes another `ListView` and eat up its space. What can I do to make it stops pushing at certain height? I've tried adding `layout-weight` or `maxHeight` but it doesn't help.

Comment: If you want to use `layout-weight`, try to set height as `match_parent` or 0dp

Comment: @PriyankVadariya interesting...what is the difference between `match_parent` and 0dp? Laptop isn't with me so I can't test this out. It would be great if you could explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing it programmatically. It seems `XML` doesn't give much control for dynamic height. I added `onLayoutChangedListener` to both `ListView` to detect height change and add height control logic in the listener.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same amount for both `ListViews` equally divided, just put them in a `LinearLayout`.

`LinearLayout` will have property `weightSum=2` while both `ListViews` will have, depending on the `LinearLayout orientation property`:

If `vertical` -> both `ListViews` will have `android:height="0dp"` and `layout-weight=1`

If `horizontal` -> both `ListViews` will have `android:width="0dp"` and `layout-weight=1`

Comment: hi, I want them to expand at their will but stop expanding at some point. `android:height="0dp"` would fix their height respective to weight.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/green_bg_duplicate"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1" />

    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```